# Browser is not opening in client side using MSSQL JDBC driver MFA authentication

Tags: java, linux, azure-active-directory, mssql-jdbc

Currently we have one database on Azure. We have one web application deployed on Headless linux server. We are connecting to this database from our application using Active Directory user. This active directory user has MFA enabled on Azure. The application uses MSSQL JDBC driver(mssql-jdbc-9.2.1) to authenticate with this database using interactive mode.

The driver has the following code to open a browser to provide AD credentials on the Microsoft portal during authentication.

```
private void openDefaultSystemBrowser(URL url) {
  try {
    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported() && Desktop.getDesktop().isSupported(Action.BROWSE)) {
      Desktop.getDesktop().browse(url.toURI());
      LOG.debug("Opened default system browser");
    } else {
      throw new MsalClientException("Unable to open default system browser", "desktop_browser_not_supported");
    }
  } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException var3) {
    throw new MsalClientException(var3);
  }
}
```

We were expecting that the driver will open up the browser in client side because our web server is running in Headless mode. So, we are getting the following exception when the driver was trying to open the browser:

```
com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalClientException: Unable to open default system browser
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByInteractiveFlowSupplier.openDefaultSystemBrowser(AcquireTokenByInteractiveFlowSupplier.java:116)
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByInteractiveFlowSupplier.getAuthorizationResult(AcquireTokenByInteractiveFlowSupplier.java:61)
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByInteractiveFlowSupplier.execute(AcquireTokenByInteractiveFlowSupplier.java:37)
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:59)
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:17)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Is there any way to delegate the browser open request to the client side from the headless linux server?